# Non-homogenous $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\ge2\sqrt{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)+7abc}.$

Tags: inequality

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c.$ Prove that$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\ge2\sqrt{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)+7abc}.$$
After squaring both side, we'll prove $$(a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc+1)^2\ge 4(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)+28abc$$
It's equivalent to $$(a+b+c)^2+(ab+bc+ca)^2+(abc+1)^2+2(abc+1)(a+b+c+ab+bc+ca)\ge 2(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)+28abc $$
But $$(a+b+c)^2+(ab+bc+ca)^2\ge 2(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) $$thus, it's enough to show $$(abc+1)^2+2(abc+1)(a+b+c+ab+bc+ca)\ge 28abc$$or$$(abc)^2+1+2(abc+1)(a+b+c+ab+bc+ca)\ge 26abc$$If we use $$(abc)^2+1\ge 2abc$$we need to prove $$(abc+1)(a+b+c+ab+bc+ca)\ge 12abc$$I got stuck here. It seems that equality holds when $a=b=c=1.$

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

By AM-GM
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc+1\ge 2\sqrt{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}+abc+1.$$And$$abc+1\ge 2\sqrt{abc}.$$
Now, let  $x=\dfrac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8}\ge y=abc\ge 0.$

Thus, we prove $$\sqrt{8x+y}+\sqrt{y}\ge \sqrt{8x+8y},$$
or $$8x+2y+2\sqrt{y(8x+y)}\ge 8x+8y \iff \sqrt{y(8x+y)}\ge 3y \iff 8x\ge y.$$Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c=1.$

Comment: Nice again! Already +1.